# How to pass data from plist based UITableView to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a `TableViewController` with a protoptype cell. It's populated with Labels and ImageViews from a `.plist` with an Array of Dictionaries. How can I pass this data to the detail View? The detail view is a `UIViewController` subclass. I've tried with methods from different tutorials but I just can't find the right combination to make it work. Code examples would be great!

```
import UIKit

class OurMenuViewController: BaseViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?




var menuItems: [MenuItem] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menuItems = MenuItemsManager.sharedManager.loadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension OurMenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->         Int {
    return menuItems.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:     NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: MenuItemTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("menuItemCell") as! MenuItemTableViewCell
    let item = menuItems[indexPath.row]

    //display data from MenuItems.plist
    cell.menuItemNameLabel?.text = item.name
    cell.ingredientsItemLabel?.text = item.ingredients
    cell.priceItemLabel?.text = item.price
    cell.menuItemImageView?.image = UIImage(named: item.image)

    if let discount = item.discount {
        cell.discountLabel?.text = discount
        cell.discountView?.hidden = false
    } else {
        cell.discountView?.hidden = true
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}
```

I have created another viewController named `DetailViewController`, so in `DetailViewController` I want to show all the details about foods from `OurMenuViewController`, but I can not pass data via segue, maybe because of lack of knowledge ;( Can You please help me how to pass data from `MenuItems.plist` (`OurMenuViewController`) to the `DetailViewController`?

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var itemNameLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet  var itemImageView: UIImageView?
private var menuItems: [MenuItem] = []
//var restaurantImage:String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    menuItems = MenuItemsManager.sharedManager.loadData()

  itemImageView!.image = ?????????????????????
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First in your storyboard you need to set Storyboard Segue Identifire to `SIDDetail` for example

Second you need to create `setData` method in your `DetailViewController` class for example like this:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var currentItem: MenuItem?
    ...
    func setData(item: MenuItem) {
        currentItem = item
    }
    ...
}
```

And then you need to override `prepareForSegue` method in your `OurMenuViewController` like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "SIDDetail" {
            if let cell = sender as? MenuItemTableViewCell {
                if let index = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row {
                    let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
                    detailViewController.setData(menuItem[index])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```